# Trigger function on Enter keypress

Tags: jquery

I've a simple search function which i Want to trigger on Enter key press, though the function executes but the form also get posted.

```
<script>
function search()
{
 ...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#text").keypress(function (e) {
if (e.which==13)
  search();
 });
});

<body>
<form id="searchForm" name="searchForm">
 <input size="40" id="text" type="text" name="text" class="input" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? There might be better ways to do it. Do you want to execute the function `search()` when the form `searchForm` is submitted?

Comment: i want to execute search when someone press `enter` key on #text

Comment: I gave you an answer, with the appropriate way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the function to the submit event and prevent the default:

```
$('form').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    /* your code here */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function search()
{
 ...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#text").keypress(function (e) {
if (e.which==13)

  search();
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

use `return false`, it prevents default action

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to listen for an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press event. You should listen for the `submit` event, which will also fire when the key is pressed.

Here is the proper way to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        search();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try returning false from your function which will stop the processing continuing.

Comment: adams comment below is the next step - preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

It's the way forms work, you should use `submit` event: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault) or just return false to cancel the natural submit action.